# Unable to unlock the previous months and dates in UIDatepicker And also showing the Time in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uidatepicker

In my project I need to show the date 18 back and lock the 100 years I tried like this I got it but here am locking days and months for that year(1912) also I need to show all the days and months for that year(1912) and one more thing when I select date it is showing along with time i Don't wanna show the time can any one solve this issue [image: check the screen shot of year] [image: showing Date along with time]

```
 -(IBAction)donePickerView:(id)sender
 {

 NSDate *minDate1 =[datePickerView date];
NSString *theDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",minDate1];

 self.dob.text = theDate;
 DatePicView.hidden = TRUE;
  datePickerView.hidden =TRUE;


}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {  
   [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];
   scrlView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
    if (textField == dob) 
{
   DatePicView.hidden = FALSE;
   datePickerView.hidden =FALSE;
   NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];

   NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];


   NSDateComponents * comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [comps setYear: -18];
   NSDate * maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];
   [comps setYear: -100];
   NSDate * minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: currentDate options: 0];

      [datePickerView setMinimumDate:minDate];
   [datePickerView setMaximumDate:maxDate];
   [datePickerView setDate:minDate];
         [dob resignFirstResponder];

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the maxDate to a -100 years.

So the maxDate is lower then the minDate, should these be the other way arround?

```
NSLog(@"Now: %@", currentDate);
NSLog(@"Max: %@", maxDate);
NSLog(@"Min: %@", minDate);


Now: 2012-10-18 10:04:43 +0000
Max: 1994-10-18 11:04:43 +0000
Min: 1912-10-18 11:45:11 +0000
```

This if you select 1980-12-12 this is lower then the max date and higher then the minimal date.

```
UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
//  add this to display date only.
[pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

[pickerView setMinimumDate:minDate];
[pickerView setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[pickerView setDate:minDate];
[[self view] addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
```

Comment: Thanq for fast replay i didnt get ur answer could explain me some more brif

Comment: the max date is lower then the minimale date, so when you select a date it can't confirm to the mindate and maxdate at the same time, just ook dat the output i've posted.

Comment: i tried in ur way but i didnt understand am very new to ios development could you please show me code then i will understand and one more thing is i need only date and years but here time also printing i dont wanna to display the time could you help me to figure out thease issue

Comment: `NSDate` will always include the time, you just don't use it.